# Push button on python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, button, click

Input email and password is right but submit doesn't click:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-aqua btn-fluid').click()
```

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV0BK.png)

Also tried by `XPath` etc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: html:
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-aqua btn-fluid">Вход</button>

Comment: Could you please edit your original question and add the relevant code in there instead of as a comment? This will help people understanding your situation much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Classname` with three words(two spaces in between them) doesn't get recognized, so you can use `xpath` to find the element.

You can find the element using the below `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='user']//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

OR (Updated answer after OP responded with an exception he is getting)

You can try clicking it my java script click, like:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='user']//button[@type='submit']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable, doesn't work, maybe that bec of ::before and ::after, I'm the begginer sry

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
import time
maybe I didn't import some lib?

Comment: @Hush i have added another way to click on the element using java script click. Please try the other way and let me know if it works.

Comment: I need to do it on python but if I understood right I should past it on the console browser. So I did it and browser send me message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Maybe exists some libs for this problem? Thanks for helping me

Comment: @Hush that is a python code only. Use those 3 lines instead of the first line that i used in my initial ans

Comment: U can try it on cite https://brandshop.ru/new/  when u logging

Comment: @Hush have edited my code, please pick the two line of code that is there now.

Comment: I launched this code and it clicked "Search" button on this cite

Comment: @Hush i opened your website and checked the element and have update my answer. Please pick the updated ans, it would definitely work

Comment: thank you so much, can u pls gimme some matetial for study. for example i actually not fully understand how arguments[0] work. TY u are my hero today :)